# What is the meaning of this statement t=(input[i]=='t' || input[i]=='T');

Tags: c, input, count, cpu-word, frequency

```
int main()//Couting the frequency of word 'the' in a sentence
{
       int i,n;
  char t,h,e,space;
    int wcount=0;
    char input[100];
    gets(input);
    n=strlen(input);
    for(i=0;i<=n-3;i++)
    {
        t=(input[i]=='t' || input[i]=='T');
        h=(input[i+1]=='h' || input[i+1]=='H');
        e=(input[i+2]=='e' || input[i+2]=='E');
        space=(input[i+3]==' ' || input[i+3]=='\0');
        if((t&&h&&e&&space)==1)

            wcount++;

    }
        printf("The frequency of word 'the' is %d",wcount);

}
```

### This C Program finds the frequency of the word ‘the’ in a given sentence. This program is used find the occurance of the word ‘the’ present in a given sentence. And displays number of times ‘the’ word has occured.

```
Can someone explain the meaning of statement:
 t=(input[i]=='t' || input[i]=='T');
        h=(input[i+1]=='h' || input[i+1]=='H');
        e=(input[i+2]=='e' || input[i+2]=='E');
        space=(input[i+3]==' ' || input[i+3]=='\0');
```

Comment: Not sure about the newer versions of the C compilers, but in the past the standard has always been that a==b returns 0 if false, non-zero if true - so checking if ((t&&h&&e&&space)==1) is not as good a system as checking if (t&&h&&e&&space).

Comment: Also, in the past, you would want to use int for t, h, e and space rather than char, as there's no guarantee that the non-zero value would fit in char.  Not sure if this has changed with the newer standards.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning is for each i th element:

1. If ith character is `t or T`. The `(char)t` variable will be assigned `true` i.e. 1. otherwise 0.
2. If (i+1)th character is `h or H`. The `(char)h` variable will be assigned `true` i.e. 1 otherwise 0.
3. If (i+2)th character is `e or E`. The `(char)e` variable will be assigned `true` i.e. 1 otherwise 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
t=(input[i]=='t' || input[i]=='T');
```

In this line the right hand side returns true if input[i] is 't' or 'T'. Otherwise returns false. If it returns true then t will be assigned to the ASCII value of 1 otherwise it will be assigned to ASCII value of 0. Next three line will work similarly to this.

```
h=(input[i+1]=='h' || input[i+1]=='H');
 e=(input[i+2]=='e' || input[i+2]=='E');
 space=(input[i+3]==' ' || input[i+3]=='\0');
```